# Is there any other solution to selected row by using renderer in java? I've tried with table.setRowSelectionInterval(); but it's not works

Tags: java

I think I have an easy problem. I'm new in Java. I don't know how to select (highlight) a single row based on input from the text field for a single row in the table. I've tried with setRowSelectionInterval(index,index1) but it's not working at all. Do you have any simple solutions for that? Thanks in advance.

```
  textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
   int rowcount = table.getRowCount();
   int colcount = table.getColumnCount();

   String str = textField.getText();
   String[] arr2 = str.split("\\|");
   String arr2split = arr2[1];
   String arr3split = arr2[2];
   table.clearSelection();
   for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
   if (table.getValueAt(i, 1).toString().equals(arr2split) && table.getValueAt(i, 3).toString().equals(arr3split)) {
       //table.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 72, 72));
       table.setRowSelectionInterval(0,0);

          }
        }
     }
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and adjust your question accordingly, ideally with a [mcve].

Comment: Assuming `table` is a `JTable` `setRowSelectionInterval(start, end)` should be the correct method. If that's not working as intenden we'll need more information, e.g. what happens, what would you expect (I assume you want to have multiple rows selected), how do you initialize the table etc. - Did you call `setRowSelectionAllowed(true)` on the table?

Comment: I've tried that as well, but it doesn't work. I expect to give me selected row or rows. I don't have any result.

Comment: Condition works very good, but function setRowSelectionInterval doesn't work. I've tried with getSelectedRow and it doesn't work to.

Comment: I have two times the same error. Exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/intellij/codeInsight/editorActions/FoldingData"while constructing DataFlavor for: application/x-java-jvm-local-objectref; class=com.intellij.codeInsight.editorActions.FoldingData

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

```
      textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
       int rowcount = table.getRowCount();
       int colcount = table.getColumnCount();

       table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);//this is the new line
       table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);//this is the new line

       String str = textField.getText();
       String[] arr2 = str.split("\\|");
       String arr2split = arr2[1];
       String arr3split = arr2[2];

       for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
      if (table.getValueAt(i, 1).toString().equals(arr2split) && table.getValueAt(i, 3).toString().equals(arr3split)) {

            table.setRowSelectionInterval(i,i);

          }
       }
    }
 });
```